# "Add to Cart" button on CMS Page - non product page

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, addtocart

So, I am seeking a way to give my customers the ability to add a product to the Magento shopping cart directly from a standard non-product page (i.e. CMS).  I am using Community Edition 1.9 and from what I understand the ability to add a product to cart via URL (query string) was removed as of 1.3.

Is there any way to add this functionality?  I am not wanting the customer to have to click directly through to the Product page to place an order.  One less step I would think could help the friction and increase overall conversions.

Any one have an idea or suggestions?   Thanks in advance for any tips, tricks, solutions...

Answer (score 3):

Call `.phtml` file from block and use this.

`<?php $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProduct()) ?>
<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product) ?>`

Answer (score 2):

Anything is possible. I'm not sure on the removed functionality but in essence all you need to do is create a form that wraps the button matching what you get on details page. Submit action on form should be add to cart controller action with product Id.

If you have issues let me know and I'll provide a gist for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a link like this one

www.example.com/checkout/cart/add?product=[id]&qty=[qty]

Please check this post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634869/outside-link-for-add-to-cart